# Magento 2 reindexing error on Product-attribute-process after migtaion

Tags: magento2, migration, indexing, reindexing

Indexing console
[image]

Everything else is working perfectly. i also disabled the elasticsearch and checked but error still there. Error is with Query, at last word "AND (())", when i remove this and run directly on Mysql, it works.
Where this Query is written so i could fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query error is related to the custom index "Product Attribute Index", so you should find which module declares this custom index by running this command in your root directory: `grep -r "Product Attribute Index" app vendor`.

Assume you found it declares in `app/code/Asif/ProductAttributeIndexer` module, run this command from your root directory: `grep -r "</indexer>" app/code/Asif/ProductAttributeIndexer` to find the `indexer.xml` file.

Once you get the `indexer.xml`, open that file to find Indexer class. Once you found the Indexer class, check the code in the Indexer class. I think that file is the answer to your question:

> Where this Query is written so i could fix it.

Comment: Exactly to the point Answer. really appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**The simple fix i would choose will be that**

> - Export your DB in self-contained file
> - open the file in a text editor or any IDE
> - Find this query and fix it
> - Then import this Database again and sync it with your project.

Comment: Ok i try this out.